# Qt - no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, qt

The error is:
no matching function for call to 'Game::drawPanel(int, int, int, int, Qt::GlobalColor)'
     drawPanel(0,0,150,768,Qt::darkCyan);
                                       ^

Im new with Qt and I started making a game. I was following a youtube tutorial and I cant find where is mistake in my code. Its the Opacity problem but on the video, guy didnt provide this argument and it worked.

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "Interface.h"

class Game: public QGraphicsView{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // constructors
    Game(QWidget* parent=NULL);

    // public methods
    void displayMainMenu();
    QString getWhosTurn();
    void setWhosTurn(QString player);

    // public attributes
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
    Interface* interface;
    QString* fight;     // wskaźnik??

public slots:
    void start();

private:
    void drawPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, QColor color, double opacity);
    void drawGUI();
    QString whosTurn_;
    QGraphicsTextItem* whosTurnText;
};

#endif //GAME_H
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Interface.h"
#include "Button.h"
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>


Game::Game (QWidget *parent){
    // set up the screen
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setFixedSize(1024,768);

    // set up the scene
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setSceneRect(0,0,1024,768);
    setScene(scene);
}

void Game::start(){
    // clear the screen
    scene->clear();

    interface = new Interface();
    interface->placeHexes();
}

void Game::drawPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, QColor color, double opacity){
    // draws a panel at the specified location with the specified properties
    QGraphicsRectItem* panel = new QGraphicsRectItem(x,y,width,height);
    QBrush brush;
    brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    brush.setColor(color);
    panel->setBrush(brush);
    panel->setOpacity(opacity);
    scene->addItem(panel);
}

void Game::drawGUI(){
    // draw the left panel
    drawPanel(0,0,150,768,Qt::darkCyan);

    // draw the right panel
    drawPanel(874,0,150,768,Qt::darkCyan);

    // place player1 text
    QGraphicsTextItem* p1 = new QGraphicsTextItem("Tekst roboczy 1");
    p1->setPos(25,0);
    scene->addItem(p1);

    // place player2 text
    QGraphicsTextItem* p2 = new QGraphicsTextItem("Tekst roboczy 2");
    p2->setPos(874+25,0);
    scene->addItem(p2);

    // place whosTurnText
    whosTurnText = new QGraphicsTextItem();
    setWhosTurn(QString("PLAYER1"));
    whosTurnText->setPos(490,0);
    scene->addItem(whosTurnText);
}

void Game::displayMainMenu(){
    // create the title text
    QGraphicsTextItem* titleText = new QGraphicsTextItem(QString("RockPaperScisors?"));
    QFont titleFont("comic sans",50);
    titleText->setFont(titleFont);
    int txPos = this->width()/2 - titleText->boundingRect().width()/2;
    int tyPos = 150;
    titleText->setPos(txPos,tyPos);
    scene->addItem(titleText);

    // create the Multiplayer button
    Button* multiplayerButton = new Button(QString("Multiplayer"));
    int bxPos = this->width()/2 - multiplayerButton->boundingRect().width()/2;
    int byPos = 275;
    multiplayerButton->setPos(bxPos,byPos);
    connect(multiplayerButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(start()));
    scene->addItem(multiplayerButton);

    // create the quit button
    Button* quitButton = new Button(QString("Quit"));
    int qxPos = this->width()/2 - quitButton->boundingRect().width()/2;
    int qyPos = 350;
    quitButton->setPos(qxPos,qyPos);
    connect(quitButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
    scene->addItem(quitButton);
}

QString Game::getWhosTurn(){
    return whosTurn_;
}

void Game::setWhosTurn(QString player){
    // change the QString
    whosTurn_ = player;

    // change the QGraphicsTextItem
    whosTurnText->setPlainText(QString("Whos turn: ") + player);
}
```

Comment: According to the error message, I see that you are not passing the opacity as a parameter. Change `drawPanel(0,0,150,768,Qt::darkCyan);` to `drawPanel(0,0,150,768,Qt::darkCyan, 1.0);` and `drawPanel(874,0,150,768,Qt::darkCyan);` to `drawPanel(874,0,150,768,Qt::darkCyan, 1.0);`

Comment: `void drawPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, QColor color, double opacity);` has 6 parameters and when you call it like this: `drawPanel(0,0,150,768,Qt::darkCyan)` you provide only 5. You have to also provide a value for the opacity. Either provide it in the call, or give a default value of 1 in the function's signature.

Comment: Or  add a default value in the header to the function:  `void drawPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, QColor color, double opacity=1.0);`

Comment: @eyllanesc what a coincidence :)

Comment: When im doing it:
/home/jakub/Pulpit/c++/build-projekt_c++-Desktop-Debug/moc_Hex.cpp:52: error: 'staticMetaObject' is not a member of 'QGraphicsPolygonItem'
     { &QGraphicsPolygonItem::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_Hex,
        ^

And there is 8 more errors :/

Comment: show the complete error message.